# .NET Regular Expression (perl-like) for detecting text that was pasted twice in a row

Tags: c#, .net, regex, perl, pcre

I've got a ton of json files that, due to a UI bug with the program that made them, often have text that was accidentally pasted twice in a row (no space separating them).

Example: {FolderLoc = "C:\testC:\test"}

I'm wondering if it's possible for a regular expression to match this. It would be per-line. If I can do this, I can use [FNR](http://findandreplace.io/), which is a batch text processing tool that supports .NET RegEx, to get rid of the accidental duplicates.

I regret not having an example of one of my attempts to show, but this is a very unique problem and I wasn't able to find anything on search engines resembling it to even start to base a solution off of.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The whole line is duplicated? Or just a part of the line? The beginning or the end of the line? Or some arbitrary text in the middle of the line?

Comment: are you talking about having the line duplicated like this? >line 1 >line 2 >line 2 >line 3?   If so, I have a solution for you.

Comment: You mean like `wasn't able to find anything wasn't able to find anything` on some lines?

Comment: @mob Just part of the line

Comment: @SJ10 Not quite, it's instead like what zdim just described.

Comment: @zdim Yes, just like that. It might be between some other text. (e.g. It just wasn't able to find anything wasn't able to find anything no matter how hard I tried.)

I've now included an example in my question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can collect text along the string (`.+` style) followed by a lookahead check for what's been captured up to that point, so what would be a repetition of it, like

```
/(.+)(?=\1)/;  # but need more restrictions
```

However, this gets tripped even just on double le**TT**ers, so it needs at least a little more. For example, our pattern can require the text which gets repeated to be at least two words long.

Here is a basic and raw example. Please also see the note on regex at the end.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @lines = (
    q(It just wasn't able just wasn't able no matter how hard it tried.),
    q(This has no repetitions.),
    q({FolderLoc = "C:\testC:\test"}),
);

my $re_rep = qr/(\w+\W+\w+.+)(?=\1)/;  # at least two words, and then some

for (@lines) { 
    if (/$re_rep/) {
        # Other conditions/filtering on $1 (the capture) ?
        say $1
    } 
}
```

This matches at least two words: word (`\w+`) + non-word-chars + word + anything. That'll still get some legitimate data, but it's a start that can now be customized to your data. We can tweak the regex and/or further scrutinize our catch inside that `if` branch.

The pattern doesn't allow for any intervening text (the repetition must follow immediately), what is changed easily if needed; the question is whether then some legitimate repetitions could get flagged.

The program above prints

```
just wasn't able 
C:\test
```

---

**Note on regex**   This quest, to find repeated text, is much too generic
as it stands and it will surely pick on someone's good data. It is enough to note that I had to require at least *two* words (with one word `that that` is flagged), which is arbitrary and still insufficient.  For one, repeated numbers realistically found in data files (`3,3,3,3,3`) will be matched as well.

So this needs further specialization, for what we need to know about data.

Comment: Fortunately for my use case, nothing legitimate should get flagged. I modified it slightly to (\w+\W+\w+)(?=\1) since there's never going to be a space separating the two. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Vopel Great.  But you need those `.+` (not for space): `\w+\W+\w+` gets two words, no more -- so `\1` that follows directly must be those two words, and so the pattern then matches only two-word repetitions.  The example in my answer would only match `C:\test` if you remove `.+`, not the other one. With `.+` we allow for more than two words (but not less); so as it is matching characters past two words it is checking whether all that is ahead again. Thus it finds repetitions of any length (like `C:\A\test` repeating).

Comment: Ah, I see. I am having a problem though. This is matching stuff that I was not expecting it to match that span several lines, like this: https://i.imgur.com/qHzUr1a.png

Comment: @Vopel I've updated the post and so am removing the two comments. In summary: This is rather broad, there's got to be cases that get flagged which are actually good data. (But it can't spread over lines, not in Perl.)  (2)  Can you show what your typical files are like?

Comment: I've adjusted it to where it's not picking up false positives anymore, thank you. I think you accidentally missed a parentheses mark after 'qr/' though.

Comment: @Vopel Great -- On a rounded problem like this one can't have a "general solution" I think; it's got to be tweaked for particular data/use cases.  ///  Thank you for noting the error and letting me know!  It's weird how such things manage to slip in ... I always test and check quite a bit, and (try to) make a point of checking the final version too.  fixed